# PHP PDO количество строк - как правильно?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

У меня есть такой вопрос. Нужно узнать количество строк, которые вернулись в результате запроса SELECT. Наткнулся на различные варианты решения, но не могу понять какой правильный. На англоязычном StackOverflow почему-то очень многие рекомендуют просто вместо `SELECT * FROM...` делать `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM...`. А если у меня запрос на пол-экрана? С вложенными SELECT'ами, JOIN'ами и прочей прелестью? Мне его что, дублировать и добавлять везде COUNT()? Это криво, ИМХО. Не хочу так.

Есть второй вариант. Делать так:

```
$result = $pdo->query( 'SELECT * FROM `foo_bar`;' );
$count_result = $pdo->query( 'SELECT FOUND_ROWS();' );
$row_count = $count_result->fetchColumn();
```

И тогда нам вернётся то, что нужно. Но сразу вопрос - какие есть ограничения/баги в таком подходе? Подводные камни, либо неочевидные проблемы.

Есть третий вариант.

```
$result = $pdo->query( 'SELECT * FROM `foo_bar`;' );
$row_count = $result->rowCount();
```

В официальной доке по PDO написано, что rowCount() не работает с SELECT-запросами. Вернее, написано, что не гарантируется его корректная работа со всеми БД. Мои тесты показывают, что MySQL и PostgreSQL `rowCount()` работает как надо.

Вопрос - как, всё-таки, правильно посчитать количество строк, которые выбрал SELECT-запрос?

P.S. `count( $result->fetchAll() )` **не предлагать**. Ибо даже на жалких 100к записей... сами понимаете.

---

пример запроса:

```
$sql="SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
    metering.id,
    metering.super_number,
    metering.contract,
    metering.name, 
    metering.city,
    metering.address,
    metering.phone,
    metering.additional_phone,
    metering.responsible,
    metering.name_metering,
    metering.number_card_customer,
    metering.date_contract, 
    metering.date_metering, 
    metering.time_metering,
    metering.status_customer, 
    metering.status, 
    metering.notification,
    metering.date_status, 
    metering.date, 
    metering.creator, 
    metering.type, 
    metering.importance, 
    metering.source_attraction, 
    metering.production, 
    metering.status_metering, 
    metering.delivery_date, 
    metering.delivery_time, 
    metering.production_date,
    user_retail.login AS login_responsible, 
    login_name_metering.login AS login_name_metering, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM prepay_metering WHERE prepay_metering.id_custom = metering.id) AS prepay,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM manufacture_cost WHERE manufacture_cost.name = metering.id) AS prepay_cost,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `communication_metering` WHERE `communication_metering`.`id_metering` = `metering`.`id`) AS comment      
    FROM `metering` 
    LEFT JOIN user_retail ON user_retail.id = metering.responsible
    LEFT JOIN user_retail AS login_name_metering ON login_name_metering.id = metering.name_metering
    WHERE
    metering.group_id = '".$_SESSION['group_id']."%' AND
    metering.id LIKE '".$_SESSION['id']."%' AND
    metering.super_number LIKE '".$_SESSION['super_number']."%' AND
    metering.contract LIKE '".$_SESSION['contract']."%' AND
    metering.name LIKE '%".$_SESSION['name']."%' AND
    metering.city LIKE '%".$_SESSION['city']."%' AND
    metering.address LIKE '%".$_SESSION['address']."%' AND
    (metering.phone LIKE '%".$_SESSION['phone']."%' OR metering.additional_phone LIKE '%".$_SESSION['phone']."%') AND
    metering.name_metering LIKE '".$_SESSION['name_metering']."%' AND
    metering.number_card_customer LIKE '".$_SESSION['number_card_customer']."%' AND
    metering.type LIKE '".$_SESSION['type']."%' AND
    metering.responsible LIKE '".$_SESSION['name_responsible']."%'
    ";
```

Это исходный запрос. Дальше два экрана того, что с этим запросом происходит:

```
$_SESSION['status_customer']=$_POST['status_customer'];
    if (!empty($_SESSION['status_customer'])) $sql.="AND metering.status_customer='".$_SESSION['status_customer']."'";
    $_SESSION['status']=$_POST['status'];
    if (!empty($_SESSION['status'])) $sql.="AND metering.status_customer=2 AND metering.status='".$_SESSION['status']."'";
    $_SESSION['contract_yes']=$_POST['contract_yes'];
    if (!empty($_SESSION['contract_yes'])) $sql.="AND metering.contract!=''";
    $_SESSION['metering_sr']=$_POST['metering'];
    if (!empty($_SESSION['metering_sr'])) $sql.="AND metering.metering='3'";
    //Дата создания
    if (!empty($_SESSION['date1'])) {
        $start_date = substr($_SESSION['date1'],6,4).'-'.substr($_SESSION['date1'],3,2).'-'.substr($_SESSION['date1'],0,2);
        $sql=$sql."AND metering.date >= '".$start_date."'";
    }
    if (!empty($_SESSION['date2'])) {
        $end_date = substr($_SESSION['date2'],6,4).'-'.substr($_SESSION['date2'],3,2).'-'.substr($_SESSION['date2'],0,2);
        $sql=$sql."AND metering.date <= '".$end_date."' ";
    }
    //Дата замера
    if (!empty($_SESSION['date_metering1'])) {
        $start_date = substr($_SESSION['date_metering1'],6,4).'-'.substr($_SESSION['date_metering1'],3,2).'-'.substr($_SESSION['date_metering1'],0,2);
        $sql=$sql."AND metering.date_metering >= '".$start_date."'";
    }
    if (!empty($_SESSION['date_metering2'])) {
        $end_date = substr($_SESSION['date_metering2'],6,4).'-'.substr($_SESSION['date_metering2'],3,2).'-'.substr($_SESSION['date_metering2'],0,2);
        $sql=$sql."AND metering.date_metering <= '".$end_date."' ";
    }
    //Дата контракта
    if (!empty($_SESSION['date_contract1'])) {
        $start_date = substr($_SESSION['date_contract1'],6,4).'-'.substr($_SESSION['date_contract1'],3,2).'-'.substr($_SESSION['date_contract1'],0,2);
        $sql=$sql."AND metering.date_contract >= '".$start_date."'";
    }
    if (!empty($_SESSION['date_contract2'])) {
        $end_date = substr($_SESSION['date_contract2'],6,4).'-'.substr($_SESSION['date_contract2'],3,2).'-'.substr($_SESSION['date_contract2'],0,2);
        $sql=$sql."AND metering.date_contract <= '".$end_date."' ";
    }   
    //Дата доставки
    if (!empty($_SESSION['date_delivery1'])) {
        $start_date = substr($_SESSION['date_delivery1'],6,4).'-'.substr($_SESSION['date_delivery1'],3,2).'-'.substr($_SESSION['date_delivery1'],0,2);
        $sql=$sql."AND metering.delivery_date >= '".$start_date."'";
    }
    if (!empty($_SESSION['date_delivery2'])) {
        $end_date = substr($_SESSION['date_delivery2'],6,4).'-'.substr($_SESSION['date_delivery2'],3,2).'-'.substr($_SESSION['date_delivery2'],0,2);
        $sql=$sql."AND metering.delivery_date <= '".$end_date."' ";
    }       
    //Постраничное отображение
    if (isset($_GET['pag'])) $pag=$_GET['pag'];
    else $pag=0;
    if (empty($_GET['lim'])) $sql .=" LIMIT ".$pag.", 30;";
```

Код не мой. Стоит задача перевести на PDO. Поэтому не хотелось бы видеть комментариев в стиле "кривые руки" и "кто так пишет", ибо будет не по адресу :) спасибо

Comment: Покажите свой запрос на полэкрана с вложенными SELECT и JOIN, а там и видно будет.

Comment: `count( $result->fetchAll() ) не предлагать. Ибо даже на жалких 100к записей..` а они там уже не хранятся на сервере после выборки что ли?

Comment: А решение, которые разрабы предлагаю, тут http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.rowcount.php в примере номер 2.

Comment: @Visman по поводу `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` я писал. Пример запроса через 5 минут добавлю в топик

Comment: @Visman добавил листинги

Comment: вы так и пишите в вопросе тогда. "Хочу вывести постранично", для этого надо знать общее число. Это меняет ситуацию, и никуда вы от запроса count  не денетесь.

Comment: @КапитанФлинт, листинги просил не я :) Коммент адресуйте therainycat.

Comment: что-то мне кажется что запрос с таким количеством `like` вряд ли будет быстрым :)

Comment: @teran там именно count ниже нужен. Постранично можно и другим способом вывести. Нужно знать общее число. Хотя на самом деле мой вопрос не касается прямо конкретно этого участка кода, вопрос более общий, для личного понимания в целом и на будущее.

Comment: ну если вы специально упрощать запрос для получения количества не хотите (а я бы настоятельно рекомендовал его упрощать, потому что выполнять подзапросы в списке выборки, которые получают prepay, prepay_cost это явно лишняя работа). То тогда  просто _оберните_ его в select count() в таком виде: `$sql="selecr count(1) from (". $sql . ") X"`

Comment: Или даже просто _замените_ в готовом запросе все от слова "select" до слова "from" на "count(1)" (один preg_raplace). если конечно в запросе нет group by в самом конце

Comment: И замечу, что вычисление count() прямо в БД это единственно не кривой вариант, так как позволяет оптимизатору БД понять, что сами данные будут не нужны и возможно по другому подойти к выполению. И самое главное, при получении количества PDO он в любом случае вытянет все строки на клиента, даже если отдавать вам их не будет. А вообще я бы подумал, нельзя ли сделать все за одну операцию, не получая количества строк заранее

Comment: @Mike стоит задача перевести на PDO. За рефакторинг никто не заплатит :) и рефакторить там по-хорошему не только этот запрос надо. Касательно COUNT(*) - сами данные тоже нужны

Comment: `FOUND_ROWS()` вполне штатный путь для решения такой задачи. Только не забывайте про `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`.

Comment: OMG, `"сами данные тоже нужны"`. Нельзя же так тупить. "сами данные" у тебя возвращают 20 строк, или сколько там в лимите указано. А count(*), про который тебе говорят, возвращает ПОЛНОЕ количество строк. Ты в состоянии понять разницу между 20 строками и "жалкими 100к записей"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**Тебе это не нужно**](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#count)

Если коротко, то `rowCount()` для селекта - это самая бессмысленная функция во всех Database API

Случаев, когда тебе может понадобиться что-то посчитать, ровно два:

1. У тебя уже есть данные, нужно знать их количество. Нет ничего проще: `count(данные)`.
2. Тебе не нужны данные, а нужно только количество. Тут только `SELECT count(*)` из базы **без вариантов.**

Всё, больше случаев нет, все любимые ламерами mysql_num_rows и rowCount не у дел.

`SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` [не слишком оптимален](https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/), и может использоваться только если общее число строк невелико. В противном случае оно будет слишком сильно нагружать базу.

Поэтому, как правильно предложено в комментариях, сделать список полей переменной, и подставлять в зависимости от запроса либо ее, либо count(*). Т.е.

```
$select = "SELECT ид, супер нумбер, Авраам родил Исаака, Исаак родил Иакова, Иаков родил Иуду и братьев его и так далее до седьмого колена...";
$from = "FROM `metering` ... и далее весь развесистый SQL без лимита";

$count = $pdo->query("SELECT count(*) $from"))->fetchColumn();
$rows = $pdo->query("$select $from LIMIT 0, 20")->fetchAll();
```

Comment: C 2007 года `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` так и не оптимизировали? Хорошая ведь идея

Comment: я интересовался этим вопросом недавно, из тех же самых соображений. Но насколько я понял - воз и ныне там.

Comment: @Ипатьев я не силен в SQL на самом деле, вопрос такой ещё - когда мы делаем вложенные SELECT'ы допустим или JOIN'ы, мы COUNT считаем только для основного SELECT'а?

Comment: @КапитанФлинт нет никакого "основного SELECT'а". Есть одна результирующая таблица из которой и делается выборка.

Comment: @Ипатьев то есть самый первый `SELECT * FROM` мы меняем на `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM`, остальное оставляем как есть? По сути

Comment: @КапитанФлинт да

Comment: @Ипатьев спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

Запрос делаешь таким образом "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM...", а в PDO делаешь после query этого запроса, fetchColumn(); оно вернёт число записей. http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php

Пример: 
Запрос: `$res =  $pdo->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table");`
Получаем число: `$countNum = $res->fetchColumn();`